# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, mysql

What i do wrong in this code? i tried to solve with "ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');" but didn't work. I think that my while is infinite loop. My column post have just 6 rows.

```
<?php
$user = $_SESSION['login_username'];
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","stringdot","Ninja123","ddbase"); 
$query = "SELECT post FROM posts WHERE username = '$user' ORDER BY date_post DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$posts = array();

while($row = $result) {
    $posts = $row['post'];
}

print_r ($posts);

?>
```

Comment: where are you changing the $row and the $result value? I believe you want a forEach loop here not a while loop on two values that you never change inside the loop.

Comment: I suppose you are happy with sql injection

Comment: is my disertation project...i make the site without any security then i secure it and i write about differences...so yes...for now i am happy with sql injection

Comment: This is the wrong approach because have the habit  of writing secure code will reduce the risk in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is born here

```
while($row = $result) {
```

the condition `$row = $result` is an assignment

This assignment will always be true as it can put `$result` in `$row`

instead `mysql_fetch_array($result)` Each loop takes the next value, if the assignment is not successful

You can resolve it with this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $posts = $row['post'];
}
```